# call system default email client from ActiveScript Flash?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to create AS3 (Flash, AIR) trigger, which would be equivalent to HTML:

```
<a href="mailto:example@blabla.pl?subject=message subject;body=message content" target="_blank" title="contakt">click to answer</a>
```

and call system email client in iOS, or Android?

**If it's possible:** 
 
What about attachments? Files are located in user documents directory (`File.documentsDirectory`).

**If not possible:**
 
What SMTP library for AS3, you recommended? I cant' connect with server on 587 port, using SMTP Mailer. I tried to modify `authenticate()` and `sendAttachedMail()` method, using request datas from the server, but I still can't establish connection.

P.S. sorry for my english ;]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `navigateToURL`

```
var u:URLRequest=new URLRequest("mailto:example@blabla.pl?subject=message subject;body=message content");
navigateToURL(u);
```

Or, you could use my [SMTP library](https://github.com/pranavh/SMTPMailer) which builds on SMTPMailer.

Just use the SMTPTLSMailer class.